# How to make a function wait 30 seconds before it starts?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

sorry still a newbie in the programming. Basically I have an Uibutton, when that button is pressed it would switch to another view, when it switches to that view, a function which calls a telephone number and sends an SMS text message out starts. What I'm trying to do it make that function wait 30seconds before it starts.

Any idea how to do this please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use:
`-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use NSTimer for that.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(myTimerMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```